# How to create a stream of lists using Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux

I am using Spring Webflux and ReactiveMongoRepository in a Spring Boot project and I want that each flux is a list of objects like below for example:

```
// 1st Flux Started:
[
{
// 1st Dashboard
},
{
// 2nd Dashboard
}
]
// 1st Flux Ended
// 2nd Flux Started:
[
{
// 1st Dashboard
},
{
// 2nd Dashboard
}
]
// 2nd Flux Ended
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ReactiveDashboardRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Dashboard, String> {
}
```

The service:

```
@Service
public class ReactiveDashboardServiceImpl implements ReactiveDashboardService {

    private ReactiveDashboardRepository reactiveDashboardRepository;

    public ReactiveDashboardServiceImpl(ReactiveDashboardRepository reactiveDashboardRepository) {
        this.reactiveDashboardRepository = reactiveDashboardRepository;
    }

    public Flux<Dashboard> getDashboards() {

        return this.reactiveDashboardRepository.findAll();
    }


}
```

The controller:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/sse")
public class ReactiveDashboardRestController {

    private ReactiveDashboardService reactiveDashboardService;

    public ReactiveDashboardRestController(ReactiveDashboardService reactiveDashboardService) {
        this.reactiveDashboardService = reactiveDashboardService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/dashboards", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Dashboard> getDashboards() {
        return this.reactiveDashboardService.getDashboards();
    }

}
```

So basically I want all the object in the array to be part of a single stream because that is how the client app I will be using is designed. For now in total there are only 3 of them. So in the each stream will hold an array of all the object. I know that this isn't the best use of webflux.
How can this be achieved, if it can be achieved?

Comment: Which data do you want to convert into that form? Be more specific and give some code.

Comment: I edited my question by adding extra information.

Comment: Is their any attribute in Dashboard class, using which the flux can be grouped? If yes, then you can group together similar fluxes and finally get a flux of list of dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an infinite Flux that sends data with interval, you need the function "interval".

To simply your code I would recommend to return you Dashboards direct in List and transform the List in Flux in your Controller.

It will be something like:

```
    List<Dashboard> lDashBoard = new ArrayList<Dashboard>(Arrays.asList(
            Dashboard.builder().name("Dash1").build(),
            Dashboard.builder().name("Dash2").build(),
            Dashboard.builder().name("Dash3").build()
            ));
    Flux<List<Dashboard>> intervalFlux = Flux
            .interval(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .map(tick -> {
                return lDashBoard;
            });
    intervalFlux.subscribe(t->log.info("Dashboards:{}", lDashBoard));
```

The output looks like:

```
2018-11-14 15:55:18.575  INFO [Dashboards:[Dashboard(name=Dash1), Dashboard(name=Dash2), Dashboard(name=Dash3)]
2018-11-14 15:55:19.073  INFO [Dashboards:[Dashboard(name=Dash1), Dashboard(name=Dash2), Dashboard(name=Dash3)]
2018-11-14 15:55:19.573  INFO [Dashboards:[Dashboard(name=Dash1), Dashboard(name=Dash2), Dashboard(name=Dash3)]
```

Comment: My idea is to push all the items to the client in one stream with an interval of 30 seconds between each stream. The flux stream will be an infinite stream.
Do you have an idea how to work on this? I am really new to reactive programming in general I have mandatory to apply something like this in my project even if the solution doesn't make sense in based on the client logic.